# Count on work history log

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table `request`:

[image: http://960design.com/temp/request.png]

and a table `requesthx`:

[image: http://960design.com/temp/requesthx.png]

A single Request can have many log updates by multiple techs.  For example, tech1 can create a log for the initial phone contact and add notes in the log section.  Then tech2 could take those notes and complete a portion of the job requirement.  Tech 3 could also be working on the same job waiting for a scheduled appointment.

If tech3 is logged in, I'd like to display a count of every open ticket for tech3.

What is the best way to accomplish this?
I've completed several ugly queries that had queries running within foreach loops to add to a count variable, but this seems like the really long way to reach a simple count total.

I've tried...

```
SELECT requesthx.hxID, requesthx.requestID,
    requesthx.datetime_gmt, requesthx.log, requesthx.techID, requesthx.status,
COUNT($requestTable.requestID) AS tickets, request.status, requesthx.techID
FROM requesthx
LEFT JOIN request 
  ON (requesthx.requestID = request.requestID)
    WHERE (requesthx.status <> 'closed'
    AND request.status = 'open'
    AND requesthx.techID = '1')
GROUP BY requesthx.techID;
```

...on a query that had 5 open tickets with techID = 1.  I only receive 1 as the count.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct the database has a way of counting this kind of information.

```
Select count(*) as "TicketCount"
From requesthx
Where techid=3
And status = "open"
Group by techid
```

Comment: Hi @William if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Using your answer as a stepping stone, I believe I have it figured out:
    `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT $requestHxTable.requestID) AS OpenTickets
      FROM $requestTable
       INNER JOIN $requestHxTable
        ON $requestTable.requestID = $requestHxTable.requestID
      WHERE $requestTable.status = 'open'
      AND $requestHxTable.techID = $techID"`

Answer (score 0):

I assume my own value for status fields in both tables

```
SELECT
    `requesthx`.`hxID`
    , `requesthx`.`requestID`
    , `requesthx`.`datetime_gmt`
    , `requesthx`.`log`
    , `requesthx`.`techID`
    , `requesthx`.`status`
    , COUNT(`request`.`requestID`) AS tickets
    , `request`.`status`
    , `requesthx`.`techID`
FROM
    `requesthx`
    LEFT JOIN `test`.`request` 
        ON (`requesthx`.`requestID` = `request`.`requestID`)
WHERE (`requesthx`.`status` ="logged"
    AND `request`.`status` ="open"
    AND `requesthx`.`techID` =3)
GROUP BY `requesthx`.`techID`;
```